# Using java file as a resource in maven project

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to add a Test.java file in the resources directory. Its in the "src/main/resources" folder and marked as resources root in the project. After the jar is created(using Maven build), i'm not able to see this Test.java file. Is it because it's compiled to a .class file? How do i add a .java file as resource in my project and have it available in jar?

If i add a file with txt extension, it's available in jar but if I use .java extension for the resource file, it's somehow ignoring it.

Comment: This question does not include any details about the process you use to create a jar. Is it maven? gradle? IDE?

Comment: By default, the Java compiler does not include .java files in the JAR file when the project is built. This is because .java files are source code files that are used to build the application, but are not needed at runtime. When the project is compiled, the .java files are transformed into .class files, which contain bytecode that can be executed by the JVM. The .class files are what are included in the JAR file.

You can tell your build tool to include .java files as a resource, but it will be specific to your build tool.  Are you using Maven or Gradle or something to build this?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I'm using Maven to build this.

Comment: Also I'm using Intellij IDE.

Comment: @old_dd Shouldn't the .java files from src/main/java be compiled to .class files? Why does maven compile .java file marked as a resource?

Comment: Why do you need to put xxx.java into the jar? Do you want to put the source code into the jar? Do you want to generate a Source Code package? try `maven-source-plugin`

Comment: @user20827241 I can't really answer why that is the default behavior, but you can tell Maven to use the .java files as a resource.  I can only post once every 30 mins so I'll submit an answer that has a POM entry for you in a bit. (unless someone else beats me to it)

Answer (score 0):

To include a .java file in the resources directory of your project and have it available in the jar file as a .java file, you will need to configure your build tool to treat the .java file as a resource rather than compiling it to a .class file.

If you are using Maven, you can do this by adding the .java file to the src/main/resources directory and adding the following configuration to your pom.xml file:

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*.java</include>
      </includes>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</build>
```

This will tell Maven to include the .java file in the resources directory when building the project and to include it in the jar file as a resource.

Comment: May I also ask why your doing this?  What are you gonna use the .java file as a resource for?